# Mix levels for Facebook game interface sounds

Tags: facebook, gameaudio, video-games

I'm working on a suite of around 25 interface sounds for a Facebook game, and wondering what kind of level to bounce the sounds out. There is no musical or ambient bed to mix the sounds against, so I'm setting the standard myself.

I usually mix music, and if I'm mastering my tracks, I'll place a limiter on the master channel and push it to 0db digital. (Let's not get into a loudness war argument here!)

In the case of the game, let's say I take what I consider to be the most important sound - the one that needs to be loudest in relation to all the other sounds - what level should this sound come out as? Should I go for full scale digital to maximise loudness, mixing the others lower in relation to this high point, or should I choose lower levels for everything so I won't risk the sounds being alarmingly loud?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wish I had replied earlier, but I would base them relative to the windows native sounds.

How I think is people tend to tune their speakers to the UI error sounds on windows. So calibrate your sounds in comparison to those.

Comment: Hey Gr00b3r, that's an excellent tip. Thanks for your answer! 

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the game. Is it running in the background or does it require your attention non-stop? That's the first thing I would consider.

Are the sounds going to be played at the level you render them at or are they going to be attenuated by the game engine? If it's the first - mixing them for loudness is a no no.

Comment: Thanks Asimov, they are good points to consider. I'll be in touch with the dev team this week so I can get a few points clarified.